# Shooting death of man - grammar

Tags: articles, present-participles

Source: http://rt.com/usa/160528-salinas-cop-fatal-shooting/

> The Tuesday afternoon **shooting death of man** alleged to have attempted to burglarize a Salinas, CA home and then expose himself to the person inside marks the second time this month — and third time this year — that officers there have come under fire for what some are calling excessive force.

What is **shooting death** and why is there not an article in front of **man**?

Comment: Its a typographical error. There should be an article.

Comment: *shooting death* is "death by shooting"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shooting death is when someone dies from being shot by a gun. In this case, police shot the man and he died. I believe there is a typographical error (see @user3169's comment), and it should read "... shooting death of **a** man ... ".